# Google Analytics track user email and current time

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I need to track `userid` and `currentTime` using `Google Analytics`.

Google Analytics does not offers user PII data.So I am doing following steps-

**Step1-**
In Order to do that I created 2 new `dimention` by the google analytics [admin panel](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/) in under the property section for `hits`.

> Admin->Property->CustumDefinetion->CustomDimention->AddNew

**Step2-** Than I changed my script by ajax call and added this data in `GoogleAnalytics` Script in the page which I am tracking

```
ga('create', 'UA-57411451-1',{'userId':customUserId });
ga('set', 'dimension1', customUserId);
ga('set', 'dimension2', entryTime);
```

**Step3-** Now I am sending `GET` request to `GoogleAnalytics` using [ga-dev-tool](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/).

**Result-** This is not giving me any data.May be there are very less user on the current page.

**Questions-**

1. Am I missing any thing or Is there any better approach for same.
2. How much delay `GoogleAnalytics` causes in reflecting data.

Below is the screenshot of google analytics ga-dev-tool result.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are using valid metric/dimensions combinations? I see you're trying to get `ga:users`, `ga:newUsers`, `ga:impressions`, `ga:AdClicks`. Are those all valid with your CDs?

Comment: I cant say,how to get it to know. I am editing my steps in question with in  a minutes what steps I did,please be in touch.

Comment: Admin->Property->CustumDefinetion->CustomDimention->AddNew.....Note scope is **hits** and **active** is checked.Is this data, sufficient or I tell you something else?

Comment: Perhaps try adding the metrics in one at a time to your query and see if you get any data at all. Even try with a metric/dimension combo that you know will work, just to see if any data is available.

Comment: no,none combination in dev tool gives me data.Is there any way to check by analytics console ui view for these dimention,In general it is showing me 3 active user today.

Comment: Absolutely, go to your standard reports and see which report metrics and dimensions give you data (ie. pageviews). Whichever metrics and dimensions you use that yield data would be what you use in your API query. What are your CDs associated with? Are they being send with an event or pageview or something else?

Comment: just a quick query can you please let me know what delay it takes,like after how much time I can get data till that time by APIs.

Comment: Standard processing times would be up to 24 hours.

Comment: thanks,In a console view I found there is  there is 2 user with my cds.